# Rebranding a suite of Windows products

Tags: windows, branding

I have a suite of Windows products I'd like to re-brand.   Some are DLLs, some are EXEs.  Some are C++ and some are .NET based.

The type of branding information is primarily strings, but may include images at some point.

Several approaches come to mind, but none of them jump out:

- Using compiler directives: build the same project with different preprocessor definitions
- Binary patching: after building the assemblies, use tools to inject appropriate information
- Abstract the branding: code the application against an IBrandingProvider, and implement the provider in a DLL
- Locally modify metadata files: Perform a local edit of all AssemblyInfo.cs / *.rc in the automated build process with the appropriate information, and build for each brand

We have this issue across 10 of our products, with two known brands each.

Are there any other approaches to consider?

Answer (score 0):

If these are Windows applications being provided to customers as a Windows Installer package (.msi file) you might develop a base, brand-neutral, package which can then receive a 'Major Upgrade' that delivers the branding. A msi [major upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/da946739-9efc-4bf0-8a9a-6f6ead3c4a34) changes the ProductCode and effectively changes a product into another product. If you provide [Multiple-Package Installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/c4a0f4d8-818d-4e60-908b-adaa2a54de95) containing both the base and upgrade, your customer would only have a single .msi package to install.